# Filer json by selecting a particular node

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am having my JSON as follows

```json
{
    "Root": [{
        "Child": [{
            "Id": "1"
        }],

        "Child1": [{
            "Id": "2"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I am getting the content as follows

```bsh
$content = (Get-Content -filepath) -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

What I need is If I pass from the script as Child1 I need to extract the following node and show

```json
"Child1": [{
        "Id": "2"
    }]
```

Comment: Is it always a direct Child of Root?

Comment: Yes `WOXXOM` only one root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using PS3+, instead of joining the lines (it's slow), read the file as one string via `-Raw`:

```ps
$content = Get-Content $filepath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

- Filtering by name, showing contents without name:

  ```ps
  $name = 'Child1'
  $content.Root.$name | ConvertTo-Json
  ```

  In PS2.0:

  ```ps
  $content.Root | Select -expand $name | ConvertTo-Json
  ```
- Filtering by name, showing name and contents:

  ```ps
  $name = 'Child1'
  ($content.Root | select $name | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '^.|.$',''
  ```
- Filtering by `Id`, showing contents:

  ```ps
  $content.Root | ForEach { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value | Where Id -eq 2 } |
      ConvertTo-Json
  ```
- Filtering by `Id`, showing name and contents of the node:

  ```ps
  ($content.Root |
       ForEach {
           $_.PSObject.Properties |
                Where { $_.Value.Id -eq 2 } |
                ForEach { @{$_.Name = $_.Value} }
       } | ConvertTo-Json
  ) -replace '^.|.$',''
  ```

Comment: Is there any possibility to Filter it by node with Name `Child` or `Child1` because my values can change so I can not hard codr

Comment: It's even simpler. I've added two examples.